# Libgdx Android app: Avoid fullscreen and show titlebar

Tags: android, libgdx

I am developing an app using Libgdx and I don't want the app to go fullscreen and want to show the title bar but the app goes to fullscreen and hides title bar despite all efforts.

Here is my `style.xml` file

```
<style name="MyStyle" parent="android:Theme.Light"></style>
```

---

Here is `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyStyle" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.mygdx.game.android.AndroidLauncher1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

---

Here is `AndroidLauncher` class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    config.hideStatusBar=false;
    initialize(new MyGdxGame(), config);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
            }
            else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
            }
        }
    });

}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            Intent act2 = new Intent(this ,AndriodLauncher2.class);
            act2.setData(selectedImageUri);
            startActivity(act2);
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: There's a solved discussion about this in the forums: http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=12668

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old but to make this work here's what I did. Based on this link: http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=12668 provided by @weirdelfb0y

1. In your **AndroidLauncher.java** replace the "initialize(new YourGame(), config);" line with:

   RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

   layout.addView(initializeForView(new YourGame(this), config));

   setContentView(layout);
2. In your **res/values/styles.xml** make sure you have the "**android:windowFullscreen**" set to **false** and the "**android:windowNoTitle**" set to **true**.

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

LibGDX might override this but try adding this to your style

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
```

Comment: tried this already..but same issue here also

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout.addView(initializeForView(new MainClass(), false));
        setContentView(layout);
    }
}
```